# Find the index of a string that contains a substring in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the index of a string element that contains a substring in an array. I tried `Array#indexOf`, but it always returns -1.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
var array = ["OTHER-REQUEST-DEPT1", "OTHER-REQUEST-DEPT2", "OTHER-REQUEST-DEPT3"]
var string = "DEPT2"
console.log(array.indexOf(string));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on the answer by SLaks, here are a few functioning examples achieving different outcomes based on the location of a string that contains a substring in an array.

```js
const array = ["OTHER-REQUEST-DEPT1","OTHER-REQUEST-DEPT2","OTHER-REQUEST-DEPT3"];
const string = "DEPT2";

console.log(array.find     (e => e.includes(string)));
console.log(array.findIndex(e => e.includes(string)));
console.log(array.some     (e => e.includes(string)));
console.log(array.reduce   ((m, e, i) => e.includes(string) ? Object.assign(m, { [i]: e }) : m, {}));
console.log(array.filter   (e => e.includes(string)));
```

Answer (score 4):

`Array.indexOf()` finds the index of the array item that *equals* its parameter.

You don't have any array elements that *equal* `"DEPT2"`.

It sounds like you want to check whether the array contains (or find the index of) any element that *contains* your string, using `.some()` or `.findIndex()` with an arrow function that calls `item.includes(string)`.